# Animated List only delete the last item not the item at the given index

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

i am trying to use the animated list widget, what i want to achieve is by pressing a button on my tile widget inside this Animated list the tile will be deleted from my data and removed from the animated list, however when pressing the button the only the last item in the last will be removed not the one at the given index

first I used a global key for the list

```
final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
```

my animated list code

```
AnimatedList(
      initialItemCount: snapshot.data[0].length ,
        key: listKey,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, Animation animation) {
          return SizeTransition(
              sizeFactor: animation,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                   Navigator.push(
                       context,
                       MaterialPageRoute(
                           builder: (context) => ProductFullScreenView(
                                 productInfo: snapshot.data[0].elementAt(index),
                               )));
                },
                child: ProductListCardVertical(
                    index: index,
                    ),
              ));
        });
```

and inside my widget i called this function

```
// function to remove the data from my database, if true then remove the tile
// remove tile 
 listKey.currentState.removeItem(
                            widget.index, (context, animation) => Container());
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Update:

this problem happened because i did not delete the data from the list, so what i did is that i created a global list of my data and assigned the list that i get from the database to that value, then i deleted the index of the item from the list inside the tile widget.